# How can I toggle a class in CSS using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, semantic-ui

```
<i class="icon slash eye" id="test" 
  onclick="registerFunction(); myFunction(this);" 
  style="margin-bottom:-20px;cursor: pointer;float:right;"></i>
```

Script

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.remove("slash");
    }
</script>
```

It is changing slash eye to eye but not vice versa. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should really be using click handlers in your script, not your markup. jQuery makes this trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just removing the class with `remove` method.

Your question almost answered itself, as the solution to it is the `toggle` method.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("slash");
    }
</script>
```

With this simple change, your code should behave as you expect now.